# Execute for loop multiple times in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have around 631 directories with 20 files in each directory.I want to execute below code for all directories so that it can update dir_1 to dir_2 till dir_631 on every iteration. I have tried double for loop but I wasn't able to make it. Thanks in advance.

```
library(TeachingDemos)

txtStart("command_split_1000/dir_1.txt")
files <- list.files(path="data/split_1000/dir_1", pattern="x*", full.names=TRUE)

total.coefs <- data.frame()

for (x in files) {
  message('Running: ', x)

  output <- tryCatch({
    ulfasQTL::findSqtl(x, geneObjectName = "gene_after_preprocess", snpFileCate = 1)
  }, print(x), error=function(e) {
    cat("ERROR :", conditionMessage(e), "\n")
  })

  total.coefs <- rbind(total.coefs, output)
  write.table(total.coefs, file = 'output_split_1000/dir_1', sep='\t')

}

txtStop()
```

Comment: Directories or files? Your post does not align to code. Do note R also has `list.dirs`? What currently happens now -only one set of directory files are processed?

Comment: There are 20 files in each directory and i have 631 directories, I want to run this code for all files present in all directories

Comment: you could create a nested loop `for dir in directories:` for file in files` where you build the path using your directories list

Answer (score 1):

Consider nesting a `list.files` loop inside a `list.dirs` loop. Also, avoid using `rbind` inside a loop as it leads to excessive copying in memory (see Patrick Burns' [R Interno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf): Circle 2 - Growing Objects). Instead use `lapply` to build a list of data frames for a `rbind` outside of looping.

```
# RETRIEVE ALL NEEDED DIRECORIES
dirs <- list.dirs(path="data/split_1000")

for (d in dirs) {
  txtStart(paste0("command_split_1000/", basename(d), ".txt"))

  # RETRIEVE ALL FILES IN CURRENT DIRECTORY
  message('Directory: ', d)
  files <- list.files(path=d, pattern="x*", full.names=TRUE)

  # LIST OF DATA FRAMES
  df_list <- lapply(files, function(x) {
      message('--Running: ', x)

      output <- tryCatch({
         ulfasQTL::findSqtl(x, geneObjectName = "gene_after_preprocess", snpFileCate = 1)
      }, print(x), error=function(e) {
         cat("ERROR :", conditionMessage(e), "\n")
      })
  })

  # ROW BIND ALL NON-NULL DF ELEMENTS
  df_list <- Filter(NROW, df_list) 
  total.coefs <- do.call(rbind, df_list)

  # SAVE OUTPUT WITH BASE NAME OF CURRENT DIRECTORY
  out_path <- paste0('output_split_1000/', basename(d), '.txt')
  write.table(total.coefs, file = out_path, sep='\t')

  txtStop()

  # RELEASE RESOURCES
  rm(df_list, files, total.coefs)
  gc()
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts, currently I am facing two problems, (1) Its not updating dir_ in txtStart("command_split_1000/dir_1.txt"), may be we need to place it inside the loop. (2) Script stops after processing few files, may be its due to memory issue, in that case may be we need to place garbage collector (gc()) and need to restart R after completing iterations for a particular directory.

Comment: Yes, move the `txtStart` and `txtStop` inside loop. *Script stops after processing few files* ... without error? R crashes? Always on the same directory? Check text files. How large are these files being handled?

Comment: Yes R crashes and system gets restarted. My original file was of 19 gb containing 12617361 lines, so I subset the main file on the basis of 1000 rows and generated 12620 files.

Comment: R terminal crashes or RStudio crashes? Try not running in RStudio for these large batch jobs but at command line without GUI in your terminal: `Rscript "/path/to/my/R/code.R"`.

Comment: I am running on R terminal on ubntu machine. It ends up by giving:

ERROR : cannot allocate vector of size 249.7 Mb

That's why I was thinking maybe we need to restart the R session after completing iterations for one directory. As if I run one by one and close R session after completing iterations for one directory, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I added a section for releasing resources with `rm()` and `gc()` calls. See if this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for udpate, I will run script now, but there is still one problem, the dir_ in txtStart("command_split_1000/dir_1.txt") is generating multiple files but not storing the command line summary. means the content of dir_1, dir_2 is empty.